# How the laravel process it's routes?

Tags: php, laravel

I am studying Laravel 5 as my new framework and I am following the video in Laracast and I got some weird error. I am displaying simple view in my controller but all I got is this error:

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\Article].
```

Here's a bit of my code:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create'); //returns error page
```

**ArticlesController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $articles = Article::all();

        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

    }

    public function show($id) {

        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));

    }

    public function create() {

        return 'Hello World'; //display error messages

    }



}
```

So I just confused because when I try to access the create() method the Laravel also read the show() method.

Is this correct? So in the route list the Laravel will read it's routes from top to bottom?

So in my route in order to prevent the error I should put first the route of create before the show?

So it should be like this?

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create'); //make it first?
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

Comment: tip: use route reource for rest example Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModelNotFoundException is a db exception fired from the `findOrFail` method if the model your trying to find don't exist

check this [redirect-if-model-doesnt-exists-modelnotfoundexception-doesnt-work-for-me](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/redirect-if-model-doesnt-exists-modelnotfoundexception-doesnt-work-for-me)

Comment: I am just confused because in my route I only called the create() method and not the show() which has a parameter ID. So that means it should skip the show() function.

Answer (score 0):

Because the /create also triggers the show url /{any}

You should do what you said, put the create route over the show route, or delegate that boring job using

Route::resource ('article', 'ArticleController')

Therefore you are getting a modelNotFoundException, because you are looking for an article with id = 'create'